# Problema buscando dato y enviarlo como JSON en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código para buscar por nombre y luego el dato encontrado lo paso a una matriz en JSON.

¿Primero debo recibir la consulta con un `mysql_fetch_array()` y luego pasarlo a un JSON con `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`?

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en mi código?

```
<?php

    include_once "conexion.php";

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['nombre'])){
        
        }else{

            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

            $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes1
                                WHERE nombre = '$nombre'");

            while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){

                $nombre_resultado[] = $resultado;
            }

            echo json_encode($nombre_resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
    }

    

?>
```

Comment: En el código falta control de errores y comprobaciones,  por ejemplo si no se encuentran datos con ese criterio.

Comment: Espero que mi respuesta sea de ayuda. Si no funciona o tienes alguna duda házmelo saber en un comentario en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar he de advertirte que tu código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string).

Para continuar, no es necesario anidar una comprobación a `$_POST` antes de comprobar la existencia de uno de sus índices.

También estás usando un bucle innecesario para obtener todos los registros de la consulta. Se pueden obtener todos con una única llamada a `mysqli_fetch_all()` (si estás usando el controlador [`mysqlnd`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqlnd.php)).

Además, como indica [@A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) en los comentarios, te faltan controles de error antes de llamar a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` (o `mysqli_real_escape_string()` como te propongo).

Un ejemplo del código corregido podría ser:

```
<?php
include_once "conexion.php";

if (empty($_POST['nombre']) === false) {
    /* Informamos del formato de los datos entregados */
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    /* Evitamos inyección SQL y errores en las consultas SQL */
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
    /* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "
        SELECT * FROM clientes1
        WHERE nombre = '$nombre'
    ");
    /* Comprobamos si la consulta fue bien */
    if ($consulta === false) {
        /* Devolvemos algún valor que sea detectable como error */
        die(json_encode(false));
    }
    /* Inicializamos la matriz: "array()" si usas PHP 5.3 o anterior */
    $nombre_resultado = [];
    /* Obtenemos todos los registros de una vez */
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
        $nombre_resultado[] = $resultado;
    }
    /* Enviamos al navegador los datos en JSON y finalizamos la ejecución */
    die(json_encode($nombre_resultado));
}
/* NOTA: No es recomendable cerrar PHP en scripts con sólo código */
```

Comment: En caso de que quiera buscar con '%%' seria <?php

 include_once "conexion.php";

 $lista = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes1
          WHERE (nombre LIKE '%busqueda%')");


 //validacion del query
 while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista)){

    $nombre_resultado[] = $resultado;
   }

   echo json_encode($nombre_resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

?> ???? aqui me tira valor nullo y el error de $nombre_resultado

Comment: Solamente dos pegas con respecto a tu código: preferiría usar consultas preparadas directamente a usar `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Según he leído, esta función es menos segura. Luego `mysqli_fetch_all` sólo está disponible con mysqlnd (el controlador nativo de mysqli), hay escenarios en que dicho controlador no está instalado y el código fallaría. En ese mismo tenor, no se recomienda usar esta función cuando se esperan muchas filas.

Comment: Gracias por tus apuntes, como siempre, @A.Cedano . Cierto en cuanto a lo de mysqlng. En cuanto a la conveniencia o no, si se esperan muchas filas ni una opción ni otra sería recomendable, porque todas se cargan a la vez en memoria (con mayor o menor eficiencia). Habría que comprobar previamente el número de registros obtenidos o bien indicar un `LIMIT` explícito.

Comment: @ari , no he entendido tu pregunta. Pero si te "tira" valor nulo es posiblemente porque no has hecho la comprobación de error que te propues en el código. Es muy importante comprobar si la consulta SQL fue bien o mal antes de obtener registros. Además, también sería muy recomendable inicializar el valor de `$nombre_resultado`.

Comment: El Manual de PHP dice que el llenado de datos dentro del `while`, cuando se esperan muchos filas, es menos costoso que aplicar `fetch_all` de golpe. Lo que digo lo dice para [`fetchAll` de PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php), pero por lógica deduzco que será parecido para mysqli. [En el Manual hay una nota](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#116673) que recomienda `fetch_all` cuando se esperan pocos datos (según esa nota es un poco más rápido y consume menos memoria).

Comment: @A.Cedano, si te refieres a la nota *Usar este método para obtener conjuntos de resultados grandes dará como resultado una fuerte demanda del sistema y, posiblemente, de los recursos de red.* se aplica por igual en ambos casos si terminas cargando todos los datos en memoria. Cuando vas a procesar registro a registro para generar un HTML (por ejemplo) entonces es lógico usar bucles y obtener uno a uno los registros para no congestionar la memoria.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo. De todos modos nunca se recomienda traer miles o cientos miles de filas, en ese caso habría que pensar en paginar los resultados.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Es una buena práctica limitar *SIEMPRE* las consultas que pudieran obtener un número elevado de registros (o incluso obtener TODOS los registros de la tabla si el filtro de búsqueda está ausente o está vacío).

Comment: @ari, [¿te importaría continuar la conversación en el chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115301/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-a-cedano). Querría saber qué código exacto has probado.

Comment: @OscarGarcia me ha funcionado el que me has escrito arriba, gracias. Como dije anteriormente, si quisiera buscar el valor por %% seria exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: A grandes rasgos sí, @ari. Sería lo mismo, pero si quieres buscar varios términos entonces el código cambiaría para adaptarse a los términos o palabras proporcionadas.